# Simplepie and slash:comments

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I use SimplePie to display an RSS Feed on my Page.
Now I want to show the number of comments.

The RSS:

```
<slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
```

How can I show this with Simplepie?

Comment: is the feed from a single feed? are the comments on your page or in the feed?

Comment: The Comments are on the Page. But in the Feed I have the <slash:comment>COUNT</slash:comment> tag.

Comment: It doesn't currently look like SimplePie Supports comments tags. you could add support by adding 2 more functions to the class like get_comment() & get_comment_tags()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`$item->get_item_tags()`](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_item_tags) to do this. At a guess, you want the `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/` namespace, with the `comments` tag.

```
$comments = $item->get_item_tags('http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/', 'comments');
```

You can then take a look at this data structure to work out what you need. At a guess...

```
$number = $comments[0]['data'];
```